# Access database with new pacakage in Laravel 4.2

Tags: database, laravel, model, controller, package

i have created package in laravel by following this link:

*https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel4-package*

it's been successful.

Now i want to make my *new package can access my database*. So that it can display all the data in 1 table.

Is it possible to implement in Laravel? How can I do that? please help.

Comment: It is possible and you could query the database using the Laravel Query Builder or Eloquent.

Comment: does it mean that I have to create models folder in my new package?

Comment: Not necessary. If your package exposes any tables then you could do so